# Reading xml file in Flink

Tags: java, xml, apache-flink

*I am trying to use flink to sync a process to read xml files from a LocalFileSystem and sync it to s3.*

---

I need to parse a taf inside each xml file and use it to send it to respective folder in s3.

For ex: my file contains  folder1 .... xxx

I need to read the value from  and send it to /folder1

I was able to read the file content and sync it to s3 but the content was coming up as line by line.

I used TextInputFormat as suggested in 
[NFS (Netapp server)-> Flink ->s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57833940/nfs-netapp-server-flink-s3)

I have tried different formats like DelimiterInputFormat etc but not successful.  I searched through google but couldnt find any solution. Isnt this something supported ?

Is there a way to read entire file or atleast value between tags ?

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env =    
  StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

// monitor directory, checking for new files
// every 100 milliseconds

TextInputFormat format = new TextInputFormat(
  new org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path("file:///tmp/dir/"));

DataStream<String> inputStream = env.readFile(
  format, 
  "file:///tmp/dir/",
  FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY, 
  100, 
  FilePathFilter.createDefaultFilter());
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, I assume that this is for a batch (DataSet) workflow. I typically handle this by creating a list of file paths as the input to the workflow, using a custom source that handles splitting these up for parallelism. Then I've got a `MapFunction` that takes the file path as input, opens/reads the XML file and parses it, and sends the interesting extracted data bits downstream.

The other approach is to use one of several Hadoop `XmlInputFormat` implementations that are out there (e.g. [this one](https://mahout.apache.org/docs/0.13.0/api/docs/mahout-integration/org/apache/mahout/text/wikipedia/XmlInputFormat.html) that is part of Mahout). There's a bit of work required to use a HadoopInputFormat with Flink, but it's doable. E.g. something like (untested!!!):

```java
Job job = Job.getInstance();
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputDir));
HadoopInputFormat<LongWritable, Text> inputFormat = HadoopInputs.createHadoopInput(new XmlInputFormat(), LongWritable.class, Text.class, job);
Configuration parameters = new Configuration();
parameters.setBoolean("recursive.file.enumeration", true);
inputFormat.configure(parameters);

...
env.createInput(inputFormat);
```

Comment: I have tried this approach by defining custom input format that extends FileInputFormat

<code>

Comment: <code>

StreamingFileSink<Tuple2<String, String>> sink = StreamingFileSink
                .forRowFormat(new Path("file:///tmp/raw/"),
                        (Tuple2<String, String> element, OutputStream stream) -> {
                            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(stream);
                            out.println(element);
                        })
                // Determine component type for each record
                .withBucketAssigner(new ComponentBucketAssigner())
                .build();
        ds.addSink(sink);
</code>

Comment: I have explicitly overrided the number of splits to 1 which is giving me whole file content as a string. I have tested the sink to another folder in my laptop and it is working.

The only problem I am facing here is, when I add new file It is not sinking even though I used FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY.

Do I need to add anything to my custom input format for these new files ?
MyFileInputFormat

Comment: <code>
public class MyFileInputFormat extends FileInputFormat 
{
    boolean end;
    public MyFileInputFormat(Path filePath) {
        super(filePath);
    }


    public boolean reachedEnd() throws IOException {
        return end;


    public String nextRecord(Object string) throws IOException {
        end = true;

        return IOUtils.toString(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    }

    public FileInputSplit[] createInputSplits(int minNumSplits) throws IOException {
       return super.createInputSplits(1);
    }
}
</code>

Comment: For a new issue (like `FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY` not working as expected) it's best to post a new question on SO (after searching to see if it's already been answered, of course)