# StreamingFileSink not ingesting data to s3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-flink

I have created simple ingestion service that picks onpremise files and ingest to s3 using StreamingFileSink.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/streamfile_sink.html

I have set up everything as per the documentation but it is not working. I tested with the sink location to another local on prem path and files are getting there (but hidden as .part files)

Does this mean part files are also send to s3 but not visible ?

...

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();        
            env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
            String path = "/tmp/component_test";

            MyFileInputFormat myFileInputFormat = new MyFileInputFormat(new Path(path));
            myFileInputFormat.setNumSplits(1);

            ContinuousFileMonitoringFunction<String> monitoringFunction =
                    new ContinuousFileMonitoringFunction<>(myFileInputFormat,
                            FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY,
                            env.getParallelism(), 1000);


            // the monitor has always DOP 1
            DataStream<TimestampedFileInputSplit> splits = env.addSource(monitoringFunction);

            ContinuousFileReaderOperator<String> reader = new ContinuousFileReaderOperator<>(myFileInputFormat);
            TypeInformation<String> typeInfo = new SimpleStringSchema().getProducedType();

            // the readers can be multiple
            DataStream<String> content = splits.transform("FileSplitReader", typeInfo, reader);

            SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, String>> ds = content.flatMap(
                    new XMLSplitter());


            //new Path("s3://<bucket_name>/raw/")
            //new Path("file:///tmp/raw/")
            StreamingFileSink<Tuple2<String, String>> sink = StreamingFileSink
                    .forRowFormat(new Path("s3a://<bucket-name>/raw/"),
                            (Tuple2<String, String> element, OutputStream stream) -> {
                                PrintStream out = new PrintStream(stream);
                                out.println(element.f1);
                            })
                    // Determine component type for each record
                    .withBucketAssigner(new ComponentBucketAssigner())
                    .withRollingPolicy(DefaultRollingPolicy.create().withMaxPartSize(100).withRolloverInterval(1000).build())
                    .withBucketCheckInterval(100)
                    .build();
            ds.addSink(sink);       
            FileSystem.initialize(GlobalConfiguration.loadConfiguration(System.getenv("FLINK_CONF_DIR")));
            env.execute();
...
```

I am looking for the part files in s3 or do I need to make any changes to StreamingFileSink to roll the part files with min size ?

...

```
09:37:39,387 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Completed checkpoint 1 for job 34d46d2671c996d6150d88a2f74b4218 (7558 bytes in 38 ms).
09:37:39,388 INFO  org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets  - Subtask 0 received completion notification for checkpoint with id=1.
09:37:39,389 INFO  org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets  - Subtask 1 received completion notification for checkpoint with id=1.
09:37:39,390 INFO  org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets  - Subtask 2 received completion notification for checkpoint with id=1.
09:37:39,391 INFO  org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets  - Subtask 3 received completion notification for checkpoint with id=1.
09:37:39,391 INFO  org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.writer.S3Committer              - Committing <BUCKET NAME>/<FOLDER1>/part-1-0 with MPU ID CEYMmUslgCnA2KcD5pslz.7dpaQuCAqmTJo6oDPv7P.Rj45O4tHrVTfDQMABxrRvdWSTwO2RoIR.r9VP2s4IMxlPtHz9r6CP_iQ7.DcP9yGDLjIN1gaLPTunAhVGuGen
09:37:39,391 INFO  org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.writer.S3Committer              - Committing <BUCKET NAME>/<FOLDER2>/part-0-0 with MPU ID ExM_.cfOZVvXHHGNakUeshSQrkLFtm3HytooPAxDet1MoXBEJYhxlEJBYyXFmeSpk7b.ElmoydrMgotnpZAgmsh6lGhQgMYoS2hFJtOZLtPCOLyJvOt3TKRecc8YqSAJ
09:37:39,391 INFO  org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.writer.S3Committer              - Committing <BUCKET NAME>/<FOLDER3>/part-2-0 with MPU ID 64._ocicEwPAwrMrI_LXcKyEfqYtISKsLsheAjgXwGdpf3qTH0qvOM2C3k8s2L6UDJ8yZfm9YEJhopgQIrL0hmFokCyMa49bzUbhgm3KQmiCVe9CoNiTEb4ETnEJCZFA
09:37:39,393 INFO  org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets  - Subtask 4 received completion notification for checkpoint with id=1.
09:37:39,394 INFO  org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.writer.S3Committer              - Committing <BUCKET NAME>/<FOLDER4>/part-3-0 with MPU ID yuFGGVfh9YOL36mUUTIAyyLehCMyQGrYoabdv0BBe.e3uCIkLYLI6S4RfnCGtFsT2pjiEJq97bfftMycp4wGW5KKX4jsrmZAfK.kqiYnMUeWWcolXKmWOktVvwHvmSpB
09:37:39,394 INFO  org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets  - Subtask 5 received completion notification for checkpoint with id=1.
09:37:39,395 INFO  org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets  - Subtask 6 received completion notification for checkpoint with id=1.
09:37:39,394 INFO  org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.writer.S3Committer              - Committing <BUCKET NAME>/<FOLDER5>/part-4-0 with MPU ID Ab7sTpLJp3fNCCYVXe2nUO5qWmYxMeYQlOssRpeawoY2LDV.a58eShdp.Anfe6YxTnVIewCmReKiYSguJS2SlBxwNRPh2ax50nCXuSdfkyVazgiNMZYMUQJjbzTxgdYW
09:37:39,395 INFO  org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.writer.S3Committer              - Committing <BUCKET NAME>/<FOLDER6>/part-5-0 with MPU ID xDbouvLhpX7q9rFrs9y93lc7wWO20L5mxKTCWFBAmAVkTWzEiGEu2bU5H2nnCrZWbcPDMePSdpOBK64lVoS8txuhLFtq_nkBfXIs2K6OY6NuTtiSDGWi4SrWwnedC6RM
09:37:39,395 INFO  org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets  - Subtask 7 received completion notification for checkpoint with id=1.
09:37:39,397 INFO  org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.writer.S3Committer              - Committing <BUCKET NAME>/<FOLDER7>/part-6-0 with MPU ID 0uZ35XrL2ShWxZL5nlY3Z1KHTSHBsQhiaJ6HZ9CbzfgxFIf7bwRNjdGHQHWPs9N0WfcpQXBM12XbNENjfILXQ6CLCx0XZrgvGHakUgeWhfeBiOURrO8xUVMT1ot7gxIY
```

...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The StreamingFileSink only works if you have checkpointing enabled. The part files are finalized as part of the checkpointing process.

The documentation has recently been updated to explain this, but for now this is only available in the nightly builds of the docs: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/connectors/streamfile_sink.html

Comment: Does flink use any intermediate storage before sending files to S3? I had the same problem as the person above and even after enabling checkpointing I don't see the file lifecycle explained in the link you shared. I basically only see _part-X-X.tmp.XXXX... and then the same file without the lower dash.

Comment: No, the files are written directly into the target filesystem, with no intermediate storage. With S3 there are some things to be aware of, however: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/connectors/streamfile_sink.html#s3-specific

Comment: @enzo -- There's also this note in the docs, which might explain what you are seeing: "Given that Flink sinks and UDFs in general do not differentiate between normal job termination (e.g. finite input stream) and termination due to failure, upon normal termination of a job, the last in-progress files will not be transitioned to the “finished” state."